# VB.NET Webforms application: Sharing global variables between code and SQL

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, azure, global-variables

I'm working on some old webforms applications. We have some clients and we currently store some of the info in a global variables class like the next:

```
Public Class globals

    Enum Enterprise
        Enterprise1 = 10
        Enterprise2 = 11
        ...
    End Enum

    Enum Brand
        Brand1 = 5
        Brand2 = 6
        Brand3 = 7
        ...
    End Enum

    ...

End Class
```

The fact is that, even we use parameters in all SQL SPs, we have some common SPs where we have exceptions for certain clients, so you will find SPs with code like:

```
if (id_enterprise = 10)
begin
... do whatever 
end
```

And as you see this "10" it is hard-coded so, it's not maintainable and thus, global variables are not totally global.

I'm not so sure about the most efficient way to deal with this, ending with **completely** global variables, but one possible solution that have come to my mind is to have a table with global variables stored in it, and in any -not defined yet- way using that values as global sql variables that can be also shared with code.

Regarding the code, on app startup I would read that table (or SP or whatever it ends being) and store read variables in app global variables (only once, of course).

What do you think about it? Does it make any sense? Any other better implementation for completely global variables that can be shared between code and SQL? FYI, we work with Azure, maybe an Azure alternative?

Comment: Can't say I disagree with saving your variables in a data table then loading them into memory, but kind of feel you might be better off loading them into a session variable rather than global

Comment: Thank you very much @Hursey, I'll take it into account. I'll just wait to see if more guys offer new approaches :)

Comment: Forgot to mention @Hursey that I've thought of globals for 2 reasons. The main is to keet all the logic around all websites, that are not a few, so I don't have to change every reference to a global and change it by session (the globas are in a library class so I don't have Session access there), and second becase there are so many variables that I could "overflow" Session :)

Comment: You might not really want to hear this, but I’m really feeling there might be a little bit of an architectural design thing going on here.  If you’ve got that many globals that are all dependent on the enterprise Id or similar, something seems off

Comment: You are completely right Mr. @Hursey, but if we start from the beginning we are working on Webforms Apps, this is a very old architecture. To add more, we also don't have a well defined data layer (DAL) and many other things, so globals is the minor of our problems, but money rules the world, and we cannot migrate the whole apps now. We started moving one to .Net Core, but it'll take time. Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting issue here. I would recommend just creating a session table in your Azure SQL database as you have suggested, then keep just a single integer/bigint variable as a session variable (ie. Session("user_session_id")). This will minimize the footprint of the application and avoid the overflow issue that you are wary of. Load the table entries at the start of the session. In each context, look up only the parameters required to complete any particular task.